# How to receive data using bluetooth after connection (in listening mode) in Delphi android

Tags: android, delphi, bluetooth

I am developing an android app in Delphi like a classic bluetooth app wherein I need to get the data scanned by a bluetooth scanner and display in a TEdit component in Firemonkey.

I was successful in connecting to the paired device and getting the 1st data scanned. But for the next series of scanning , I dont know where to call the `FSocket.ReceiveData`. In java, there is a listening function call that waits for incoming streams, how do I do it in Delphi android pls?

Here is my code:
code snippet from sample classic bluetooth in rad:

```
procedure TForm1.SendData;
 var
  ToSend: TBytes;
  LDevice: TBluetoothDevice;
  Buff: TBytes;
 begin
  if (FSocket = nil) or (ItemIndex <> ComboboxPaired.ItemIndex) then
 begin
    if ComboboxPaired.ItemIndex > -1 then
 begin
    LDevice := FPairedDevices[ComboboxPaired.ItemIndex] as TBluetoothDevice;
    DisplayR.Lines.Add(GetServiceName(ServiceGUI));
    DisplayR.GoToTextEnd;
    FSocket := LDevice.CreateClientSocket(StringToGUID(ServiceGUI), False);
   if FSocket <> nil then
     begin
      ItemIndex := ComboboxPaired.ItemIndex;
      FSocket.Connect;
      ServerConnectionTH.FServerSocket.Accept(500);
     .....

//after successful connect, go to another form , focus in a TEdit then scan,
//currently uses this function to get data

 function TForm1.getBLData: string;
    var
    Buff: TBytes;
    s:string;
  begin
     FSocket.ReceiveData;
    Buff := FSocket.ReceiveData;
    frmLoadGrid.Edit1.Text:='';
    frmLoadGrid.Edit1.Text:= TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Buff); //enters read data 
    result:=s;
   end;
```

Can anyone pls help... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! Here' s example of using `ReadData` method: 
https://github.com/Appmethod/Appmethod115/blob/5f8ca9a9a1994d917bfbb062f9e5fd44564da6a5/Object%20Pascal/Mobile%20Samples/Device%20Sensors%20and%20Services/Bluetooth/BlueChat/uChatManager.pas .

A common idea is you should create a separate thread, which run a cycle until program is terminated or your own conditions. In this cycle thread calls `ReadData` and has `FOnTextReceived` event.
Please note you need to use `Synchronize` method if you want to access visual components from other threads.

Comment: This is what I think I need! Thank you! I'll try it right away